# How to persist a change in a DBML

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table of users called `Users`

And a view called `UsersActive` that filters out deactivated users.

When I create my DBML, I drag the Users table in, then I change the property on the table to point to UsersActive.

This works well, until the DBML gets re-created.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried overriding the

```
[Table(Name="dbo.Users")]
```

attribute in a partial class but get the error:

```
Duplicate 'Table' attribute
```

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

-Ev

Comment: dont change the property on the table to the view, just add the view directly to the canvas like you do with tables (drag + drop).

Comment: But will this maintain the relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add the View to the DBML, just like a table...yes?

**Update:** No, it will probably not maintain the relationships -- views don't have relationships.

It sounds like your goal is to query active users in a simple way, without having to specify the criterion in each query?

What you might do then is to have a [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c) class with a method of GetUsers(). That method does the Linq query and ensures that the active criterion is always there.

Perhaps the method would have a signature of Respository.GetUsers(bool includeDeativated = false). Calling GetUsers() without arguments will not return deactivated, but you can override it if desired.

Comment: But will this maintain the relationships?